# How to retrieve 2nd latest date from a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to retrieve second latest date from a table. For example, consider this as my table:

```
COL1| COL2|   COL3
---------------------
A   |   1 | 25-JUN-14
B   |   1 | 25-JUN-14
C   |   1 | 25-JUN-14
A   |   1 | 24-JUN-14
B   |   1 | 24-JUN-14
C   |   1 | 24-JUN-14
A   |   1 | 23-JUN-14
B   |   1 | 23-JUN-14
C   |   1 | 23-JUN-14
```

I come up with this query which would get the result I want(2nd latest date).

```
SELECT sub.COL1, sub.COL2, MAX(sub.COL3)
FROM (SELECT t.COL1, t.COL2, t.COL3
  FROM test t
  GROUP BY t.COL1, t.COL2, t.COL3
  HAVING MAX(t.COL3) < (
                        SELECT MAX(COL3)
                        FROM test sub
                        WHERE sub.COL1=t.COL1 AND sub.COL2=t.COL2
                        GROUP BY COL1, COL2)) sub
GROUP BY sub.COL1, sub.COL2;
```

As you can see it's big and messy statement with multiple nested sub queries just to get a 2nd latest date. I would love to learn an elegant solution for my problem rather that this mess. Appreciate your help.. :)

**PS: I am not allowed to use 'WITH' command.. :(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
SELECT col1, col2, MAX(col3) 
FROM TEST 
WHERE col3 < (SELECT MAX(col3) 
              FROM tab1)
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2edf0/6)

Comment: This is clean and simple. How the hell I didn't think of this... :s Thanks btw.. :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by col3 desc) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: this is an awesome solution. I've learnt something new today (Rank/ dense_rank).. XD